# Multi domain connect with single react build

Tags: php, reactjs, connection

My current project developed by code PHP and now we are planning to migrate react. The current architecture of the website, we have 500 client domains and each client domain is having individual folder and in that folder is having index.php, .htaccess file alone. Index.php file includes common folder. In that integrate folder having all major codes, like login flow, payments and all data layouts.

Now we are planning to keep all domain folders as same core PHP and change common folder as React Build.

I could not able to connect each client websites to single build. Plase find my current folder structure .

[image]

Please help on this. How do I connect multi index.php file to single react build. When any one open client website, how  can I show common react layout inside of html website?